# How to add a nXn matrix to the collection from database in anylogic

Tags: anylogic

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wtGp3.png)

if this the data base and i want add all of it to the collection. But from the default options i can only add a particular column.

Is it also possible to define the row value to a variable? Suppose the matrix size is 32X4 and variable is A - the value of A should be 32

How to do this in anylogic??

Comment: Sure is possible, but not sure why you would need it? You already have your data in a nicely structured way and now you want to "un-structure" it again into an Array? Would it not be much better to use SQL and query the data that you need?

Comment: ahh okay but i dono how to do with SQL. i need it juz to read no of rows in an array or matrix to assign that value to an variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you can do is create a class that contains 4 variables column1, column2, column3 and column4
Let's call this class TheClass

your collection will have elements of type TheClass, so each element of your collection will have the information of the row of your database.

Now, why would you even want to do this? I don' know

Comment: i am trying to use a genetic algorithm in anylogic for finding the disassembly steps. for that i need to define no.of parts in the product. as the products are different. i want to take this data from data base. so i wanted to read the no.of rows data table and give it to a variable. which in turn shows no.of parts in product